# Android application can't launch some videos from YouTube

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I try to play video from YouTube in the application. Some videos are launching, but for some I get an error 'Video is not available'!
I have no idea what is the difference!

My code:

```
    mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Done initializing");
                
                //youTubePlayer.loadVideo("G5ws-ztZ0xU"); // <-- this is working!
                 youTubePlayer.loadVideo("K0PtPOtMCy4&t=9s"); // <-- this is not working!

            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you need to take the video id from the 'Share' window:

[image]